# Agora que o StackOverflow foi comprado por outra empresa o que muda por aqui?

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

Segundo essa comunicação oficial do próprio StackOverflow a empresa foi comprada pela Prosus.

https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/

Na prática, qual é o impacto disso na nossa comunidade?

O que podemos esperar de mudanças, ou nada vai mudar?

Comment: Eles compraram até o [IFood](https://www.prosus.com/companies). Pessoalmente gostaria que monetizassem a plataforma.

Comment: No momento, a resposta oficial parece ser de que "*por enquanto, nada muda*": https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/365056/401803 | https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366280/401803

Comment: *"Pessoalmente gostaria que monetizassem a plataforma"* humm boa ideia, se pudermos ser monetarizados tbm por participar :D

Comment: Se sendo apenas comunitário aparece respostas erradas heldpdesk, sugerindo trocar X por Y para tentar resolver o problema no tranco (hoje vi muitas desse tipo, até de usuário com score alto), imagine se for monetizado, ai cai de vez a qualidade das respostas.

Answer (score 9):

## Resposta curta

Não sei.

## Resposta longa

Foi feita a [mesma pergunta no meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365050/401803), e lá você pode ver várias respostas especulativas. Até porque, no momento, a única coisa que podemos fazer é isso mesmo: especular.

Não temos como saber, a não ser que você seja bem próximo de algum diretor da SE, pois até onde vi, nada nesse sentido foi divulgado. O [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow) só tem aquele lero-lero corporativo típico que não diz nada. No próprio meta.SE pude perceber que até os funcionários foram pegos de surpresa, o que indica que foi algo decidido somente no alto escalão, e não sei se algo já foi divulgado entre os funcionários.

Lá tem [uma resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/365056/401803) da [*Head of Product, Engineering & Community*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/704608/teresa-dietrich), que basicamente diz que por enquanto, nada muda:

> *The TL;DR is not much this year. We have our current strategy, roadmaps and plans for this year and continue to be focused on those. It’s business as usual, as it says in our blog post, we would be operating independently. The leadership team is staying, including me. Most of the company just found out about this today and many are in shock and excited about the future. Prosus is very community-focused and excited about what you all have built. As we start to plan for 2022, I think we will see more opportunities to invest in our public platform sites and community. I will be publishing my State of the Stack blog and meta post this month and will go into more detail there.*

Em tradução livre (ênfase minha):

> Resumindo, não muda muita coisa este ano. Temos nossa estratégia atual, roadmaps e planos para este ano e continuaremos focados neles. É o de sempre, como dito no blog, continuaremos a operar de forma independente. As lideranças permanecem, inclusive eu. **A maior parte da empresa ficou sabendo disso hoje** e muitos ainda estão chocados e animados com o futuro. Prosus é muito focada em comunidades e animada com o que construímos. Assim que começarmos a planejar 2022, acho que veremos mais oportunidades para investir nos sites públicos e na comunidade. Estarei publicando no blog e no meta, quando darei mais detalhes.

E de fato, [foram publicados no blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/16/state-of-the-stack-q2-2021) mais "detalhes". Se bem que é mais do mesmo, basicamente uma reafirmação de que "nada vai mudar".

---

Também foi feita [uma pergunta específica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365074/401803) sobre a privacidade dos dados, já que a Prosus também é dona do iFood, OLX, e [muitas outras empresas](https://www.prosus.com/companies), ou seja, eles já tinham o meu telefone e endereço (além de saber meus hábitos alimentares), e como eu uso o mesmo email em todas (inclusive aqui), juntar isso com os dados do Stack Overflow é trivial.

Inicialmente teve uma resposta insossa dizendo que ["*nada vai mudar, não se preocupe*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366280/401803), mas hoje foi colocada [outra resposta em caráter oficial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366594/401803), dizendo basicamente que nossos dados estão seguros, que a Prosus não cruza os dados de empresas diferentes, que leva a sério a privacidade, etc. Se é verdade, só o tempo dirá...

Ainda sobre esta questão, [recentemente a Política de Privacidade foi atualizada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370216/401803), e [aqui](https://gist.github.com/pxeger/f00bae9440f0c8bc5d88c389c84b9e47/revisions#diff-4e8eff6c864aa6ec56c1f7ae983cb7889a3349e48e60d19bf0bf5cb0fe5213bf) é possível ver o que mudou. Um trecho relevante e relacionado ao assunto é: "*WE DO NOT AND WILL NOT SELL YOUR PERSONAL INFORMATION*", enfatizando todo o discurso de que nossos dados estão "seguros", etc.

---

Enfim, eu acho que não temos como saber o que vai acontecer. Por mais que a SE diga que nada vai mudar, não há garantias. Pois muitas empresas que são compradas vêm com esse discurso, mas sabemos que nem todas cumprem o que foi dito.

**<cinic-mode>**
Eu diria que, **se** algo mudar, será de repente e de forma unilateral, sem se importar com a comunidade (como tem sido o *modus operandi* da empresa nos últimos meses).
**</cinic-mode>**

Comment: Valeu a contribuição man. Então parece que nem os insiders sabem de algo a respeito, ou se sabem ainda não abriram o bico...

Comment: Resposta sensata!

Answer (score 7):

Só vou responder o que dá e vou explicando melhor o que estou escrevendo aqui.

O [metão tem uma discussão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365050/140010) aberta e lá tem informações melhores já que conta com respostas de funcionários e ex-funcionários.

Claro que funcionários dirão o que a empresa mandou.

Não há dúvidas que no curto prazo muda nada, não havia um estado emergencial para uma mudança drástica. No longo prazo tudo pode acontecer, embora altamente improvável, é possível até o site deixar de existir (só estou colocando isso porque pode acontecer, mas não acredito, não faz sentido).

Em geral esse tipo de compra costuma virar a chave do interesse do que a empresa deve alcançar e agora o lucro pode fazer parte do objetivo central. Se isso começar um processo inicial quase imediatamente ou não, só podemos especular e com poucos subsídios. O fato é que a maioria das empresas da Prosus dá prejuízo e eles estão bem com isso por enquanto.

Entrando no campo absoluto da opinião, não vejo melhoria e acho que a tendência será fortalecer a ideia da quantidade ser mais importante que a qualidade, ainda que continue de forma velada.

E pra dizer a verdade já não faz muita diferença porque a qualidade só existe (com raras exceções) no conteúdo antigo. Atualmente o SO é uma fonte de *fake news* na programação. Só o dia de hoje já vi várias perguntas e respostas no SOpt com SQL Injection. A comunidade não aguenta mais ficar falando sobre isso e muitos usuários, alguns até bem ativos, não ligam para isso, eles gostam de ensinar errado. Cansa enxugar gelo e não ter uma ferramenta melhor.

Não vejo que a ferramenta vá melhorar. Os desenvolvedores são competentes, mas a direção não quer dar o próximo passo e em algum momento a tal da [destruição criativa de Schumpeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creative_destruction) dará conta do problema, como o SO deu com outras coisas antes.

O que posso dizer que é para se pensar como as coisas funcionam. Um grupo de pessoas receberam dezenas de dólares por resposta que demos e não ganhamos nada. É para se pensar o quanto queremos colaborar com esse tipo de empresa. Nós fizemos tudo isso ser um sucesso e nem somos ouvidos.

É claro que pode melhorar agora, quem sabe tenha um nova visão para criar valor real para as pessoas em vez de só criar valor na base do amontoado. Sonhar não custa nada. Mas outras empresas do grupo tem atuação bem mais *evil* que o SO, então não mantenha grandes esperanças. Eu acho que se venderá cada vez mais ilusões, mas torço estar errado.

É certo que algumas pessoas sairão da empresa, algumas não tinham motivação mais, algumas ficaram milionárias e não precisam mais disso. Espere uma piora do tratamento da comunidade (não muito porque a piora já é bem patente).

Pode haver mudanças bem fortes, podemos nos arrepender bastante de ter participado disso. Mas pode mudar o objetivo inicial e quem sabe começarem cobrar para as pessoas terem respostas, e pagar para quem as dá. Improvável, mas tudo é possível.

Essa discussão é basicamente irrelevante, pelo menos neste estágio, teremos que fazer isso com algo concreto que mude no futuro.

Vamos aguardar a marcha dos acontecimentos.

Tudo isso serviu de lição, acabou minha ingenuidade com *startups* que prometem revolucionar a sociedade na era digital.

Comment: Legal a sua visão Maniero, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Resposta interessante!

Answer (score -8):

A Prosus também espera em breve unir forças com a Skillsoft, uma plataforma de treinamento mais voltada para negócios.
Pode ser a forma de monetização que possivelmente será implantada.
ou não...