# O que é uma resposta ruim?

Tags: debate, novo-recurso

Sou novo na comunidade bem como sou novo na programação. Desde que comecei a programar me empenho bastante para realmente aprender e não simplesmente copiar códigos. Consigo encontrar praticamente tudo em sites, blogs e comunidades quando não consigo compreender a documentação oficial, inclusive aqui no Stackoverflow.
Uma vez que precisei recorrer a esta comunidade, de fato não havia encontrado uma solução para o meu problema, era um problema simples de ser resolvido para quem já está a mais tempo na programação, mas não estava claro, para mim pelo menos, na documentação oficial. À época, minha pergunta nem chegou a ser respondida por ser considerada irrelevante, o que até compreendo, mas não era algo do tipo: “preciso que alguém faça para mim”, queria apenas um caminho.
Recentemente, quis começar a interagir um pouco na comunidade, como eu disse anteriormente, sou iniciante, então peguei algumas dúvidas de usuários que eram simples de resolver. Ajudar é gratificante, mas o resultado de ajudar nessa comunidade pode ser frustrante e desmotivador para quem está começando, o que talvez até explique o motivo de eu não ter obtido uma resposta quando precisei, ainda que de um iniciante como eu, mas que conseguiria, talvez, resolver aquela situação específica. As respostas são revisadas e, mesmo que resolvam o problema, elas recebem uma avaliação ruim e sequer sabemos o motivo para que possamos melhorar como programador e membro da comunidade.
Do pouco que observei, para uma resposta ser boa, ela tem que ser mais complexa do que a documentação oficial de qualquer tecnologia, além da pergunta ser relevante, qual o sentido disso?
O meu intuito não é fazer uma crítica, mas sim uma sugestão para que seja obrigatório um comentário sempre que for feita uma avaliação negativa de uma resposta, de forma que nós saibamos o motivo e nós mesmos possamos melhorá-la.

Comment: Pelo que disse você tem respostas que foram negativadas. Normalmente os usuários que tem publicações negativadas vem ao META de forma arrogante e a primeira coisa que faço e ver o histórico de publicações e fazer uma análise técnica da qualidade. Todos os usuários que fiz a tal analise acabaram excluindo a conta pois é difícil ter os equívocos publicamente expostos ainda mais da forma que embateram com a comunidade.

Comment: Você ao contrário está perguntando numa boa, querendo entender um processo que pode vir a ser traumático, então o pergunto: Você tem três respostas negativadas, eu ainda não as li, tem certeza quer que seja feita a análise técnica dessa. Só não fique chateado comigo se o resultado não o agradar.

Comment: Quanto a sugestão de comentar os votos alguns fazem esse comentário, mas nem nem todos os usuários que recebem esse comentário são maduros o suficiente para distinguir uma orientação de um ataque pessoal. Aqui já fomos agredidos das mais vis formas apenas por fazer uma observação. Então o voto é secreto e o comentário é opcional justamente para não expor nosso usuários a fúria de egos dilacerados.

Comment: Não há necessidade de avaliar, não estou julgando, e jamais ficaria chateado por um erro meu ser exposto, muito pelo contrário, como eu disse, estou começando agora e ainda tenho muito a aprender. Também não é do meu feitio agredir ninguém, ainda que verbalmente, de forma alguma. Também não pedi que a pessoa que avaliou fosse identificada. Eu apenas sugeri que em casos de avaliação negativa em uma resposta, nós pudéssemos ser informados o motivo, somente, de forma a melhorar a qualidade em nossas futuras respostas.

Comment: Sobre não ser obrigatório comentar ao votar, sugiro que leia [este FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357437) (infelizmente só tem em inglês), que explica os motivos de ser assim (e principalmente, porque parece que isso não mudará tão cedo). Ou seja, para mudar isso, teria que ser uma proposta que rebata todos os pontos explicados lá, além de convencer não só uma fatia considerável dos usuários, mas também a empresa responsável pelo site (essa é a parte mais difícil, aliás) de que isso seria benéfico (ou ao menos, que isso seria menos pior do que é hoje).

Comment: Por fim, essa ideia já foi discutida várias vezes, seguem algumas: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/112052 | https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8295/112052

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações.

Answer (score 7):

Não temos como avaliar o caso específico da pergunta, pois ele não foi *linkado* e especificado. Mais ou menos vale o mesmo para as respostas, apesar de podermos achar, não sabemos o que não concorda.

O que eu achei foi uma pergunta, postada duas vezes, que não é adequado, sem cuidado mínimo na edição dela. Esse tipo de coisa desagrada quem está aqui há anos, todos os dias, o dia todo, parando seu trabalho importante, se esforçando para ajudar as pessoas, sem ganhar nada para isso, e não ver o mínimo esforço por parte de quem pergunta. Eu vi que não negativei nenhuma das duas, mas quando vejo algo que a pessoa não se esforçou não me dá vontade de responder, provavelmente algo dará errado, não haverá reconhecimento, tem chance razoável da pessoa não entender, ou seja, levanta bandeiras vermelhas que algum problema ocorrerá. Não vale a pena perder tempo com isso pela experiência adquirida.

Pode ter ocorrido o mesmo com as respostas. Vi algumas e vi um padrão comum, vou citar algumas coisas para ajudar a todos, como é objetivo aqui. E como por esse item.

Respostas boas:

- ajudam o coletivo e não o individuo
- são bem postadas, caprichadas
- explicam o que está fazendo e não apenas entrega pronto
- estão corretas em todos os sentidos
- não são duvidosas ou só opinativas
- não respondem perguntas ruins, por exemplo quando respondem um "faz pra mim" ou de pergunta já feita antes, ou ainda que não dá para saber ao certo o que está perguntando
- não repetem o que já foi postado
- não são plágios, vandalismos ou spam
- respondem dentro dos parâmetros citados
- tem algum embasamento e referências, não é só um "acredite em mim"
- não seja só o que já tem em outro lugar
- não conta com a sorte para ter bom retorno, possui método, igual é exigido na programação.

Algumas são mais importantes que outras, não quer dizer que a falha de uma inviabiliza toda resposta, mas pode ocorrer.

Lembrando que a avaliação é de toda comunidade e que não está presente em todos os cantos, então é inerente existir dois pesos e duas medidas.

Eu até acho ruim o fato de não ter tanto *feedback*, mas é que cansa. Quase todo mundo cansou. Quase nunca dá resultado. Muitas vezes atrai a ira do interlocutor.

As pessoas sinalizam como abusivo ou assédio comentários feitos pelo sistema com um texto pensado para ser simples, objetivo e tranquilo, dentro de uma empresa que adota completamente o politicamente correto e os funcionários são diversos.

Mesmo que algumas pessoas sejam sensatas, você não sabe quem, cachorro mordido por cobra tem medo de linguiça. Ninguém quer ser atacado por fazer seu trabalho voluntário. Pela insensatez de muitos (poucos daria para se virar) a situação fica complicada e todos pagam um preço. Não é o ideal, eu reconheço isso, mas é compreensível.

Aqui no meta tem bastante informação que ajudam entender com mais detalhes tudo isso, inclusive no quadrinho amarelo (muda de cor em certos monitores) aí do lado. Praticamente tudo o que a pessoa quer saber já foi respondida. Quando não tem uma pergunta específica sobre o site pode ser postada aqui. [Pode ajudar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Aqui no meta já foram sugeridos diversas vezes obrigar dar um comentário, não vou falar sobre o assunto, sempre rejeitado por não ser prático e cair no que acabei de citar. Ainda que fosse o ideal, não é viável. O novo recurso não rolará, a não ser que alguém invente uma forma que funcione, nunca conseguiram.

Sabe o que tem em comum com pessoas que fazem boas perguntas e respostas? Elas leem a documentação de tudo o que usam. Quem não faz isso, por definição, não conseguem dar boas respostas ou escrever boas perguntas.

Entende que suas respostas não encaixam bem em alguns dos itens citados? Consegue melhorá-las?

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, mas não vejo motivos para o tom de arrogância. Estou aqui para aprender e, futuramente, poder ajudar, assim como você, sem ganhar nada em troca. Entendo perfeitamente que minhas respostas talvez não se encaixem nos itens citados, mas não era sobre isso, era sobre como melhorar a comunidade através dos novos usuários.

Comment: É justamente o que eu estou dizendo aí. Eu só dei uma resposta ao que foi perguntado, se eu soubesse que seria recebido assim, eu nem teria respondido. Vou provou porque é melhor deixar sem *feedback*. Eu usei argumentos, você só usou ataque, sem fazer oque sugere que as pessoas devem fazer, mostrando o que tem de errado, sem atacar, portanto seu comentário parece mais arrogante, pelo menos em um ponto, até desvalorizando a parte boa dele. Sua pergunta fala do seu caso, se era só sobre comunidade não deveria citar seu caso.

Comment: @CristianoLeite, é exatamente isso que eu estava falando sobre as pessoas não suportarem análises técnicas. Em momento algum o Maniero foi arrogante, por sinal foi muito educado e solicito. O que o incomodou e as pessoas não estão acostumadas é receber uma critica técnica, isenta de sentimentos ou subjetividades.

Comment: Não quero causar mais desconforto, peço desculpas se não entendi a forma como o @Maniero colocou. Os links citados acima já me mostraram a extensão do problema. Obrigado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques ironicamente contradizendo o que ele disse lá em cima (`jamais ficaria chateado por um erro meu ser exposto`). Enfim, a gente já tem experiência, alguns chegam mais polidos, mas acaba sendo o mesmo resultado, é uma pena, por isso não avançamos.

Comment: Não estou chateado, só não vejo sentido mais nessa discussão. Te pedi desculpas por não ter entendido a forma como você colocou o seu posicionamento, quando você cita que não está ganhando nada pra isso soa sim arrogante. Eu só fiz uma sugestão, assim como vários outros usuários. Entendi o seu ponto de vista e @AugustoVasques me esclareceu bastante coisa também, inclusive em uma pergunta recente que fiz. Acredito que o caminho seja deixar claro do que se trata a comunidade.

Comment: No início, sempre quando temos dúvidas em relação a programação a maior referencia é o SO e isso nos dá uma visão errada.

Comment: É, temos um conceito bem diferente do que é arrogância. Pelo menos agora sabemos do ponto específico que estava se referindo.

Comment: @CristianoLeite, nós somos pessoas normais trabalhamos, temos contas e família para sustentar, os mesmos problemas que todo mundo tem. Realmente nós trabalhamos de graça pois gostamos da proposta do site. O problema não está em trabalhar de graça, o problema está em todos os dias de cinquenta a cem vezes por dia temos que ficar ensinando repetidamente a usar o site quando temos vasta documentação e discussão sobre com utilizar o site, ao usuário basta clicar no símbolo de interrogação(?) no canto superior direito da barra de navegação do site ou usar o painel de destaques na entrada do site.

Comment: Quero para ir para outro assunto e toda hora sou arrastado para o que já era par ter sido resolvido. Estou deixando de da uma resposta no site principal por não mais ter tempo tenho que ficar dando satisfação a quem não quer entender. Quer usar um produto leia as instruções antes:  [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045)

Comment: @CristianoLeite 
"*quando você cita que não está ganhando nada pra isso soa sim arrogante*" - Ele só está dizendo que não recebe dinheiro para participar do site. Aliás, ninguém recebe, todos nós o fazemos de graça no nosso tempo livre, e afirmar isso não tem nada de arrogante, é apenas uma constatação. Os únicos que ganham dinheiro são os [donos do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8615/112052) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo aliás, em nenhum momento eu falo em EU, falo de todas as pessoas ativas do site.

Comment: Pior que não ganhar dinheiro para ajudar as pessoas, é gastar tempo para ajudar e ver que esse tempo gasto não é efetivo. Muitas vezes uma tentativa de indicar o caminho correto é interpretada como ataque, para quem gosta de ajudar acaba sendo frustrante